# proper way to reference an unbound aspx control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controls, abstraction

If you have an unbound textbox on a aspx page and want to reference it in code, what is the best way to abstract the control?

I would like to reference it as a property rather than as a control like: string textbox = Request.Form["myTextbox"]. I am not sure where a property should be created to expose the textbox. 
Thanks

Comment: I am afraid you mint be kinda missing the whole concept of ASP.NET MVC and how it differs from classic ASP.NET WebForms and *aspx controls*. If you are talking about *aspx controls* maybe you should read some getting started tutorials about ASP.NET MVC which explain how this concept of controls doesn't exist anymore. In ASP.NET MVC you might consider using view models in your Controllers to get the values that are submitted from the client in a strongly typed fashion.

Comment: you don't reference a textbox in controller code , ever.  You can use the value that was in the textbox.

Comment: also - use tags for your question like you did , asp.net-mvc , but don't also make a title like "MVC ..."  we got that from the tag

Comment: I am confused. I need a value from an unbound textbox from an aspx page. I may misunderstand but I thought unbound controls are not connected to the model. I am trying not to make a reference to the textbox! I thought the best way to access something externally is through a property.